# Como verificar se meu usuário está online asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Quero bloquear para ele não poder usar o mesmo login em várias máquinas.

Então preciso saber se ele está online, como faço isso no asp.net identitty?

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual o objetivo de negar o login? Seria uma espécie de controle de licenças? ou segurança?

Comment: controle de licença Jose, por exemplo. O que impede de uma empresa contratar teu software para 1 usuário, e usar em todos os setores? rsrsrs

Comment: Entendi. Pra isso você vai ter que criar um controle de acessos um pouco mais complexo, trabalhando em conjunto com o Asp.Net Identity. Tenho algumas sugestões, talvez eu elabore uma resposta com uma possível solução, quando tiver tempo sobrando.

Comment: Jone, eu andei vendo para usar SignalR, aí eu deixo uma lista de usuários logados em memória, algo assim...

Comment: É uma excelente opção. Já fiz algo parecido com o uso de SignalR em uma aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

As conexões http não se mantém abertas. Desta forma, você não tem como saber se um usuário está logado ou não.

A solução mais comum para este tipo de problema seria o padrão heartbeat. Você faz um javascript que, de tempos em tempos (com setInterval), manda uma requisição ajax para o servidor para informar que o usuário ainda está navegando na tua aplicação.